# I cannot use the INTERSECT operator

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, intersect

I'm trying to resolve this exercise:

'Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.'

I tried resolving it using the INTERSECT operator like this:

```
SELECT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'O'
OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'E' OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'I' OR
LEFT (CITY, 1) OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'U'

INTERSECT

SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'O'
OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'E' OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'I' OR
RIGHT (CITY, 1) OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'U';
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT
SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR RIGHT(CITY, 1)' at line
```

What am I doing wrong and what other way do I have to solve this exercise?

Comment: MySQL doesn’t support INTERSECT.

Comment: You should learn to use parentheses for boolean expressions: `WHERE (LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR ...) AND (RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR ...)`. Or use regex as GMB suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Query the list of `CITY` names from `STATION` which have vowels as both their first and last characters.

You seem to be overcomplicating this. As I understand the question, you just need a `where` clause that filters the table once - regexes come handy for this:

```
select city
from station
where city regexp '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

The pattern describes a string that starts and ends with a wovel (`^`  represents the beginning of the string, and `$` is the end).

If you have duplicate `city` in the table, then use `select distinct city from ...`  instead.

If you want to use `left()` and `right()`:

```
select city
from station
where 
    right(city, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    and left(city, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT CITY1 AS CITY
FROM
(
    SELECT CITY AS CITY1
    FROM STATION 
    WHERE LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'O'
    OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'E' OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'I' OR
    LEFT (CITY, 1) OR LEFT(CITY, 1) = 'U'
) AS T1 JOIN (
    SELECT CITY AS CITY2
    FROM STATION
    WHERE RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'A' OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'O'
    OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'E' OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'I' OR
    RIGHT (CITY, 1) OR RIGHT(CITY, 1) = 'U'
) AS T2 ON CITY1 = CITY2
```